# Number Format Exception while working with BigInteger

Tags: java, algorithm, exception, rsa

I ran into an NumberFormatException issue while trying to decrypt a message using an RSA algorithm. Here's the method I am using for that.

```
public String decrypt(ArrayList<BigInteger> encryptedMessage) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (BigInteger bigInteger : encryptedMessage) {
        result.append((char) Integer.parseInt(modexp(bigInteger, key, n).toString()));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

And here's the modexp method(modPow).

```
public BigInteger modexp(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger n) {
    if (b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger t = modexp(a, b.divide(BigInteger.TWO), n);
    BigInteger c = t.multiply(t).mod(n);
    if (b.mod(BigInteger.TWO).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        c = a.multiply(c).mod(n);
    return c;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can convert `BigInteger` directly to `String` using its `toString()` method. No need to convert to `Integer`.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.